# from tsvector get array sorted by positional information instead of alphabetical order?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

Postgresql tsvector type contains alphabetically sorted lexemes along with positional information.
How to get sorted array of lexemes from tsvector, sorted by their positional information instead of alphabetical order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready-to-use feature for this but you can write a custom function to get what you want, e.g.:

```
create or replace function reorder_tsvector(vector tsvector)
returns text[] language sql as $$
    select array_agg(concat(pos, ':', ar[1]) order by pos::int)
    from (
        select string_to_array(elem, ':') ar
        from unnest(string_to_array(vector::text, ' ')) elem
        ) s,
    unnest(string_to_array(ar[2], ',')) pos
$$;


select to_tsvector('english', 'a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats');

                     to_tsvector                     
-----------------------------------------------------
 'ate':9 'cat':3 'fat':2,11 'mat':7 'rat':12 'sat':4
(1 row) 

select reorder_tsvector(to_tsvector('english', 'a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats'));

                      reorder_tsvector                       
-------------------------------------------------------------
 {2:'fat',3:'cat',4:'sat',7:'mat',9:'ate',11:'fat',12:'rat'}
(1 row)
```

---

Update. My versions of the OP's function:

```
create or replace function tokenize_orig_1(p_string text, p_dictionary regconfig)
returns text[] language sql as $$
    select array_agg(lexeme order by positions)
    from unnest(to_tsvector($2, $1)) arr
$$;

select tokenize_orig_1('a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats', 'English');

    tokenize_orig_1      
---------------------------
{fat,cat,sat,mat,ate,rat}
(1 row)
```

or with duplicates:

```
create or replace function tokenize_orig_2(p_string text, p_dictionary regconfig)
returns text[] language sql as $$
    select array_agg(lexeme order by pos)
    from unnest(to_tsvector($2, $1)) arr,
    unnest(positions) pos
$$;

select tokenize_orig_2('a fat  cat sat on a mat - it ate a fat rats', 'English');

        tokenize_orig_2        
-------------------------------
 {fat,cat,sat,mat,ate,fat,rat}
(1 row)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to work, Please, suggest if there is a better way.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.tokenize_orig(
    p_string text,
    p_dictionary regconfig)
  RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$ 
/* This function turns documents into array of lexemes, keeping original order of lexemes. */ 

select array_agg(lexeme) 
from 
    (
    select (arr).lexeme as lexeme 
    from 
        (select unnest(tsv) arr 
        from to_tsvector($2, $1) as tsv) arr 
        where array_length((arr).positions, 1) > 0 
        order by (arr).positions
    ) as qry

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
```

Comment: The function loses lexemes that occur more than once, perhaps this is your assumption. Note that it will work only in Postgres 9.6+ (`unnest(tsvector)` is unknown in earlier versions).

Comment: See my modified answer.

Comment: Yes, the intention was to extract unique lexemes, without duplicating.